# Loading an OBJ file, how to use normals (#vertices < #normals)

Tags: c++, opengl, normals, wavefront

I have an obj file and have succesfully loaded the object to opengl without using the normals given.
This is how it looks:
[image: tree without normals]
The format of the file is:

```
v x y z
vn x y z
f x//x' y//y' z//z'
```

The displaying function of the mesh is like that:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for all faces
{
    glVertex3f(.., .., ..);
    glVertex3f(.., .., ..);
    glVertex3f(.., .., ..);
}
glEnd();
```

And the result is this:
[image]

I've read that the object might look flat due to the default normal vector that OpenGL uses for lighting equations.
This could be solved with normals. The normals given are 780 and the vertices 155.

I've tried using glNorm before each glVertex3f call but the obj looks completely weird (lines, etc).

What should I do?

**EDIT #1:**
This is how I read the file:

```
void loader(class mesh &tree)
{
int vx1, vx2, vx3, vn1, vn2, vn3;
ifstream file;
string line;
point vec, norm;
face tempface;

file.open("tree.obj"); 
if (file.is_open() == true)
{
    while(getline(file, line) )
    {
        if (line.substr(0,2) == "") continue;
        else if (line.substr(0, 2) == "v ")
        {
            istringstream numbers(line.substr(2));
            numbers >> vec.x >> vec.y >> vec.z;
            tree.vectors.push_back(vec);
        }
        else if (line.substr(0,2) == "vn")
        {
            istringstream numbers(line.substr(2));
            numbers >> norm.x >> norm.y >> norm.z;
            tree.normals.push_back(norm);
        }
        else if (line.substr(0,2) == "f ")
        {
            face f;
            line = line.substr(2,line.length());
            for (string::iterator it = line.begin(); it != line.end(); ++it)
            {
                if (*it == '/')
                {
                    //erase both of the "//"
                    line.erase(it);
                    line.erase(it);
                    //add a space between the numbers
                    line.insert(it, ' ');
                }
            }
            istringstream inp(line);
            inp >> f.vert_indices[0] >> f.norm_indices[0] >> f.vert_indices[1] >> f.norm_indices[1] >> f.vert_indices[2] >> f.norm_indices[2];
            tree.faces.push_back(f);
        }
        else 
            continue;
    }
    file.close();
}
}
```

And this is how I am displaying it:

```
    void mesh::displayMesh()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for(vector<face>::const_iterator it = faces.begin();
        it != faces.end(); ++it)
    {
        //glVertex3f(normals[it->norm_indices[0] -1 ].x, normals[it->norm_indices[0] -1 ].y, normals[it->norm_indices[0] -1 ].z);
        glVertex3f(vectors[it->vert_indices[0] -1 ].x, vectors[it->vert_indices[0] -1 ].y, vectors[it->vert_indices[0] -1 ].z);
        //glVertex3f(normals[it->norm_indices[1] -1 ].x, normals[it->norm_indices[1] -1 ].y, normals[it->norm_indices[1] -1 ].z);
        glVertex3f(vectors[it->vert_indices[1] -1 ].x, vectors[it->vert_indices[1] -1 ].y, vectors[it->vert_indices[1] -1 ].z);
        //glVertex3f(normals[it->norm_indices[2] -1 ].x, normals[it->norm_indices[2] -1 ].y, normals[it->norm_indices[2] -1 ].z);
        glVertex3f(vectors[it->vert_indices[2] -1 ].x, vectors[it->vert_indices[2] -1 ].y, vectors[it->vert_indices[2] -1 ].z);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

The function displayMesh is called within Render function of openGL and the loader function is called into Setup OpenGL function and the mesh tree object is a global variable.

**EDIT #2:**
This how the tree looks with the normals:
[image: tree with normals]
Also [this is the code](http://pastebin.com/zp7gGc7h) of the setup function of OpenGL.

Comment: If you open your OBJ with Blender (or other 3D editor/viewer) it is displayed correctly?

Comment: Adding only `glNormal3f` calls before your `glVertex3f` functions won't have an effect unless you enable both OpenGL lighting `glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)` and at least one light, e.g., `glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)`.  Lighting will be computed with all of the default lighting settings for materials, light colors, etc.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira: Yes, I opened it in Blender and it appears much better that when I loaded it with opengl.

Comment: @radical7: Also, I have enabled lighting in my code `glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);` and still nothing. I've updated the question and added two pictures.

Comment: It looks to me like you are reading some of the vertices wrongly. Are you _certain_ that every line in the file has the format you are reading? That there is nothing unusual about any of the lines in the obj file?

Comment: Yes it shouldn't it be wrong. It's been given to be loaded for an assignment. And since the first picture is ok (in means of shape) why would I be reading the vertices wrongly?

Comment: Could you provide some code? As J99 stated, something fishy is going on with the loading/reading. Either you load the vertices correctly but display them incorrectly (memory-accesses), or load them incorrectly and display them correctly (in terms of memory-accesses). You could try to use glNormalPointer and glVertexPointer (if not already done so) and see if this changes anything.

Comment: @Juicef: I've added the loader code and the display function as well. If you need more info tell me. I am not familiar with these functions, I'll try to use them in a few hours.

Comment: Print every vertex, normal and face definition at the console and check if it matches the contents of the OBJ file. This way we can exclude the parser being the problem.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira: But there are about 780 normal vectors supplied and 155 vertices :/ How am I supposed to check the 780 normal vectors? Should I make a proram or start checking it with my eyes?

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira: I've found my error! Look at the display function the commented lines. I wanted to load normals and I was calling glVertex3f and not glNormal :/ But still the item looks as if it has no shadow (like the 1st picture).

Comment: Just cheking a few coordinates might be enough. Would you mind posting a new image with the new results (or it render just like the first image?)? Are you using any directional light? If you are using only ambient light, your model will not have any shadows.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira: Is the w coordinate needed? I haven't saved it, due to the use of glVertex-3-f. I've checked some of the coordinates of vertices, normals and faces and they appear ok. I've added the code of my setup function as well.

Comment: When you say directional light you mean the w coordinate == 1.0? Also, I am using ambient, diffuse and specular but as I've just tested with commenting these `glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambientLight ); //glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseLight );
 //glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specularLight); ` the result is the same. So there's something wrong with the lighting?

Comment: Might be as well as not. Depending on how the light attenuation factors are set some of the effects might not reach your model. Also, your shineness factor may not be correctly set. Despite these, all your code seems right to me.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira: It's really frustrating :/ The shininess factor? Which one is that? Thank you for your help!! 
Update: Tried with a moving source of light and noticed some differences at the tree but not much..

Comment: Take a look at this page: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html It explains how to setup all the attenuations and shininess. The shininess is related to the specular light.

Comment: What's the status on this? Make sure your ambient light isn't too bright, and if nothing else works, wtry adding `glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE)` around where you declare your `glClearColor`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you have the following in your draw code instead?

```
glNormal3f(normals[it->norm_indices[0] -1 ].x, normals[it->norm_indices[0] -1 ].y, normals[it->norm_indices[0] -1 ].z);
glVertex3f(vectors[it->vert_indices[0] -1 ].x, vectors[it->vert_indices[0] -1 ].y, vectors[it->vert_indices[0] -1 ].z);
glNormal3f(normals[it->norm_indices[1] -1 ].x, normals[it->norm_indices[1] -1 ].y, normals[it->norm_indices[1] -1 ].z);
glVertex3f(vectors[it->vert_indices[1] -1 ].x, vectors[it->vert_indices[1] -1 ].y, vectors[it->vert_indices[1] -1 ].z);
glNormal3f(normals[it->norm_indices[2] -1 ].x, normals[it->norm_indices[2] -1 ].y, normals[it->norm_indices[2] -1 ].z);
glVertex3f(vectors[it->vert_indices[2] -1 ].x, vectors[it->vert_indices[2] -1 ].y, vectors[it->vert_indices[2] -1 ].z);
```

EDIT: oops, you realized that already

If you want to check if the normals are correct, color each vertex according to it's normal. Use `glColor3f` but supply the normals.

Comment: If I do that, what is the output to expect? Many colours?

Comment: Faces will be colored according to the normals. For example upwards facing faces will be green, since the normals y component is positive.

Answer (score 0):

when you use erase it invalidates the iterator

```
//erase both of the "//"
it = line.erase(it);
it = line.erase(it);
//add a space between the numbers
it = line.insert(it, ' ');
```

however you can erase once and then replace

```
//erase both of the "//"
it = line.erase(it);
//add a space between the numbers
*it = ' ';
```