# Did not understand .obj file

Tags: c++, opengl

```
v 0.437500 0.164063 0.765625
...
vn 0.664993 -0.200752 0.719363
...
f 47//1 1//1 3//1
...
f 1//7 11//7 9//7
f 1//7 9//7 3//7
```

This is how my obj file look like. Could you please help me to understand this .obj file. What does each row and column stands for? How do I visualize it. I am trying to load a model using Java3D API.

[Link to loading .obj file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637498/loading-an-obj-file-how-to-use-normals-vertices-normals)

```
glNormal3f(normals[it->norm_indices[0] -1 ].x, 
           normals[it->norm_indices[0] -1 ].y, 
           normals[it->norm_indices[0] -1 ].z);
```

So, I couldn't understand the above code. I want to know what exactly is the code doing.

Comment: What is it you don't understand? If you read the OBJ specification, the code should become trivial. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

Comment: i wouldn't have posted here if i had understood :)

Comment: Taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file : Faces are defined using lists of vertex, texture and normal indices. I.e each face has 3 or 4 (tri/quad) sets of numbers. Each of those sets include 3 items - vertex, texture and normal indices. Since you've only got 2, and the middle one is missing, your faces don't have texture co-ords.

Comment: can you please explain me about the code written above.

Comment: Yeah fine, but **what** don't you understand? What specifically don't you get. If the answer is "everything", you've got some studying to do. If not, tell us what is unclear.

Comment: It's a file describing the attributes of a 3D model such as Vertices/Faces/Edges/Normals/UV's,
 Separation by Groups/Objects,
 Materials/Textures,
 Nurbs curves and surfaces.

Comment: the main thing that i didn't understood is how to write glNormal3f(x,y,z) . How to specify those x, y and z

Comment: Those values are specified in the `vn` lines. You'll have to retrieve them using the appropriate indices defined on the `f` lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`normals` is a `std::vector` containing a struct with `x`, `y` and `z` floats. These are the same as those in the `vn` lines in the .obj file. These are indexed with 0 based indices.

`it` is an iterator of a vector containing structs with `vert_indices` and `norm_indices`, these are the same as you'll see in the `f` lines. These are 1 based indices.

Thus you can get the normal of a point by getting the norm_indices of the face and subtracting 1.